There is no application set to open Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix
I am exploring SQL Server Analytic Services on a MacOS (Monterey) and tried to download the extension in this link for Visual Studio 2022:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16
However, after downloading the extension, I get that message and cannot figure out how to open it. I have Visual Studio 2022 installed successfully. Does anyone have any ideas why I am running into this issue? Is this because the extension is only available for Windows?
